# How to correctly override ISupportInitialize implementation

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I'm stuck at a point with `ISupportInitialize`.

We use a custom class inherited from System.Windows.Form.BindingSource.
Now we need to enhance the `ISupportInitialize` implementation from our inherited class to check for controls/components on the form automatically, since manual work should be minimized where possible.

The problem is, that the interface is explicitly implemented from microsoft and so i cannot call the `BeginInit()` and `EndInit()` Methods of the base class nor override it.

Just implementing new methods would stop the base class from working as usual since the methods will not get called, will they?

any hint appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty interesting question!

In my opinion the only way to call the explicitely implemented methods in the base class is to use reflection. Something like this should do the job (untested):

```
public class YourBindingSource : BindingSource, ISupportInitialize
{
    public void BeginInit()
    {
        Type baseType = base.GetType();
        InterfaceMapping interfaceMapping = baseType.GetInterfaceMap(typeof(ISupportInitialize));

        foreach(MethodInfo targetMethod in interfaceMapping.TargetMethods)
        {
            bool isBeginInitMethod = ...; // Could be determined by checking the name..
            if(isBeginInitMethod)
            {
                targetMethod.Invoke(this, new object[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not override it, and looking at the source with reflector tells me you won't be able to do much here... You could try to use the decorator pattern for all the interfaces, but chances are you will get stuck either way, since this class is used by the framework and you don't control it's usage.

Anyway, if you want to try it, here's the idea:

- create a class that implements all interfaces from BindingSource
- keep an actual BindingSource instance as a private field
- implement all interface methods by simply forwarding calls to the private field
- for the methods you want to extend, add custom logic before or after calling the original method

Something like this:

```
public class MyBindingSource : ISupportInitialize // + all other interfaces
{
    private BindingSource _original; // to be set in constructor

    public void BeginInit()
    {
        // custom logic goes here
        _original.BeginInit();
    }

    // ... (all other forwarding implementations)
}
```

Again, this would rely on all client code (also in the framework) to go through the interfaces, something I would not put money on.

Answer (score 1):

I use a couple of extension methods to achieve this:

```
public static class ISupportInitializeHelper
{
    const string BEGIN_INIT = "System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize.BeginInit",
                 END_INIT   = "System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize.EndInit";

    public static void InvokeBaseBeginInit<T>(this T obj)
        where T : ISupportInitialize
    {
        var baseType   = typeof(T).BaseType;

        var methodInfo = GetBeginInitMethodInfo(baseType);

        if (methodInfo != null)
            methodInfo.Invoke(obj, null);
    }

    static Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> s_beginInitCache = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();

    private static MethodInfo GetBeginInitMethodInfo(Type type)
    {
        MethodInfo methodInfo;

        if (!s_beginInitCache.TryGetValue(type, out methodInfo))
        {
            methodInfo = type.GetMethod(BEGIN_INIT,
                                        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                        BindingFlags.Instance);

            s_beginInitCache[type] = methodInfo;
        }

        return methodInfo;
    }

    public static void InvokeBaseEndInit<T>(this T obj)
        where T : ISupportInitialize
    {
        var baseType   = typeof(T).BaseType;

        var methodInfo = GetEndInitMethodInfo(baseType);

        if (methodInfo != null)
            methodInfo.Invoke(obj, null);
    }

    static Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> s_endInitCache = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();

    private static MethodInfo GetEndInitMethodInfo(Type type)
    {
        MethodInfo methodInfo;

        if (!s_endInitCache.TryGetValue(type, out methodInfo))
        {
            methodInfo = type.GetMethod(END_INIT,
                                        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                        BindingFlags.Instance);

            s_endInitCache[type] = methodInfo;
        }

        return methodInfo;
    }
}
```

In your class, explicitly implement `ISupportInitialize` and call the appropriate extension method, for example:

```
public class MyBindingSource
    : BindingSource,
      ISupportInitialize
{
    void ISupportInitialize.BeginInit()
    {
        this.InvokeBaseBeginInit();

        // More begin init logic
    }

    void ISupportInitialize.EndInit()
    {
        this.InvokeBaseEndInit();

        // More end init logic
    }
}
```

You don't have to explicitly implement both methods, because the base class already implements it, so if you're only interested in adding logic after initialisation, you can leave out `BeginInit()`.